# Is it possible to commit/rollback SqlTransaction in asynchronous?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to commit/rollback `SqlTransaction` in asynchronous. But it look like asynchronous is not supported. Is there any way to make it asynchronous without using raw SQL to start transaction?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2014/01/07/synchronous--vs-asynchronous-transaction-commit-trading-for-performances-with-delayed-transaction-durability-in-sql-server-2014.aspx

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thanks for the information. But it is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for avoiding thread blocking in C# side.

Comment: Did you look for TransactionScope as well? It has features to deal with async.

Comment: @MicaëlFélix Thanks. But I'm not working with .NET anymore.

Comment: No, `TransactionScope` cannot do it either. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44159992/1178314).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. Going through the relevant code, all the other methods are asynchronous through and through (the synchronous version is the special case), while `SqlTransaction` and the other relevant code is synchronous only. For the parts that overlap, the `SqlTransaction` simply synchronously waits for task completion (e.g. when handling reconnects).

In fact, as you get through the depths of the code, the transaction operations *explicitly forbid* any asynchronous operations, so not including asynchronous transaction operations seems to be by design. If you do find a workaround, keep this in mind - the system is not designed to allow concurrent operations, so *always* use `await` as soon as you get the (whatever) task back.

If you wanted to go around this, you'd have to dig all the way down to creating the binary messages for SQL Server directly (or at least using reflection to execute some of the internal helper methods), which is not going to be all too easy (and it would require you to get access to the internal TCP connection used by `SqlConnection`, of course - and handle the reconnects etc.).

Looking at EntityFramework code, their solution is pretty simple - they just call `Commit`. This isn't as crazy as it might sound - the brunt of the work is done in the `ExecuteXXXAsync` methods themselves, the `Commit` is "free" - it only costs you the communication with the server, which usually isn't too expensive.

Given those limitations, your performance still shouldn't be affected noticeably - your thread pool might have to allocate a thread or two over the usual amount if you've got a few concurrent `Commit`s, but the alternative is much more painful.

Comment: Slight aside: because T-SQL has commands for transaction management (`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` / `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `ROLLBACK` / `COMMIT`) you don't *really* need to go all the way down to the level of TDS. I still wouldn't recommend overriding the designers on this, but you could make a wrapper that issued SQL statements asynchronously to manage the transaction. This may not necessary play nice with code unaware of the fact that you've started a transaction, though.

Answer (score 6):

With .Net Core 3.0, it is now theoretically doable to commit or rollback asynchronously a transaction, with any transaction deriving from `DbTransaction`. So with `SqlTransaction` too.

See [.Net Core issue #35012](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35012). (Or [DbTransaction documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbtransaction).)

But more important for your concern, `SqlTransaction` underlying implementations do not leverage it yet: you can call async methods on it, but currently (up to .Net 7 at least and very likely with .Net 8 too) as far as I can see in the source code of [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlTransaction.cs), they are still delegating to their sync counterparts through [`DbTransaction` default implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Common/DbTransaction.cs). And this is of course the case also with [`System.Data.SqlClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/3.1-publicPoolNames/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlTransaction.cs) (no async overrides).

It can be checked on the documentation too: [`DbTransaction.CommitAsync` remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbtransaction.commitasync#remarks):

> The default implementation of this asynchronous method delegates to its synchronous counterpart and returns a completed `Task`, potentially blocking the calling thread.

And [(Microsoft) `SqlTransaction` methods list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction#methods): no overrides listed for async methods.

And also [(System) `SqlTransaction` methods list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction#methods):

> `CommitAsync(CancellationToken)`: Asynchronously commits the database transaction. (Inherited from `DbTransaction`)

So you can get your code ready to commit or rollback asynchronously with .Net Core 3.0 or higher, but you will have to wait quite more to get them actually async.

There is an issue about it [here for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/113). It does not look like it will come any time soon. (And it should never come for `System.Data.SqlClient`, since it is frozen since .Net Core 3.1.)

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Scopes are not about `SqlTransaction`, but System.Transactions, which is an entirely different interface. And this scope option does only allow to query the database asynchronously without wrecking the scope. It does not cause the commit or rollback to be async: [they stay synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44159992/1178314). So, this does not answer the question in any way.